# Do we unconsciously favour one eye when we sight-read?

Tags: sight-reading

If you were to make a musician wear an eye patch over one of their eyes as they sight-read a piece for the very first time, would you expect their accuracy to be different depending on which eye was covered? Would the accuracy be better still if both eyes were uncovered (assuming that vision quality is the same for both eyes)? If there were differences, how would you explain them?

Comment: Sight reading is more pattern recognition, like normal reading. It is not an alignment procedure like shooting where you cannot two eyes with one sight, hence favouring one. Do you experience troubles reading work one eye?

Comment: I strongly suspect that left- or right-**eyed**-ness will quickly swamp any left- or right-brained tendency when your exercise is performed. My right-eyed-ness is so strong that I was treated for lazy eye when I was 5-6, and even to this day, I can catch my left eye wandering badly if I opt to go double-vision in the mirror, and I see a substantial shift in my image in the mirror if I cover my right eye. The musician just might be disoriented by the point of view of the non-dominant eye, or find the sheet music objectively harder to read with it given the same head position (e.g. tilts right).

Comment: The notion of "left brain vs right brain" is a relic of outdated understandings of the brain (https://www.healthline.com/health/left-brain-vs-right-brain), and music frequently gets pulled into its pseudoscientific morass ("Do left- or right-brained people make better musicians?"). I've never heard the idea that one could "access" one hemisphere or the other simply by looking out of one eye, but that sounds even more imaginary. What *is* true is that you can't sight-read what you can't see, so whatever hinders your visual acuity will hinder your sight-reading. Vote to close, since...

Comment: ... Vote to close, since this is a question about either optometry or neuroscience, with hints at a false assumption.

Comment: The idea of "left vs right brain" is not true, but even if it were, the visual pathway has part called optic chiasma that splits the left part of field of view from both eyes to right hemisphere and vice versa. To see the sheet music with one hemisphere you'd need to look past it so that you see it out of the corner of your eyes, and peripheral vision isn't good enough for reading.

Comment: BTW, editing a question to a different one after it has been answered is not cool, even if the original one didn't make sense. Just ask a new one.

Comment: @ojs I was going to say that OP should roll back my edit if that is not what they meant to ask. I made the edit because I believed the question seemed to otherwise be good but the title seemed like it was just a badly-chosen phrasing of "which eye". We can roll it back if needed, but I would say we should check to make sure the question is on-topic if it asks about neuroscience. It just seemed to me like the "right-left-brained" stuff in the title was entirely tangential to the "which eye" question, so I thought I was clearing it up.

Comment: Thank you user45266 I've reworded the question, removing the brain reference.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense to me; some people are left-eye dominant, and others are right-eye dominant. Are you interested in what happens when the dominant eye is covered? Is this really a question for an opthalmologist?

Comment: I'm with @exnihilo on this - anyone who's ever tested themselves for left- or right-eyed-ness knows that they **consciously** favour one eye when they sight-read. If they're anything like me, a book for children brought up the test.

Comment: "unconsciously favor..." - something about eye dominance, and "wear an eye patch" are really two very different scenarios. One is basic question, the other describes an experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This answer concerns itself only with "reading" in the sense of symbol recognition and does not address the auditory, tactile, spatial, or motor aspects of music reading.*

---

In Shentong Wang and Mark Agius's ["The Neuroscience of Music: A Review and Summary"](https://www.psychiatria-danubina.com/UserDocsImages/pdf/dnb_vol30_noSuppl%207/dnb_vol30_noSuppl%207_588.pdf), music-reading is shown to be a highly complex and significantly bilateral activity. Of particular important for the question at hand are the [fusiform gyrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusiform_gyrus) (Rhythm reading) and superior parietal cortex (Melody reading) (Stewart 2005). See especially Table 1 in the linked article. The images below show the bilateral nature of these structures.

An earlier study of (language) reading found no difference between monocular and binocular speed. See Knehr, C. A. 1941. ["The effects of monocular vision on measures of reading efficiency and perceptual span"](https://doi.org/10.1037/h0061308). *Journal of Experimental Psychology* 29/2: 133–54.

**Fusiform gyrus (shown in red)**

[image: Fusiform gyrus]
(Image source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusiform_gyrus))

**Superior parietal cortex (lobule) (shown in blue)**

[image: Superior parietal cortex]
([Image Source](https://nba.uth.tmc.edu/neuroanatomy/L1/Lab01p14_index.html))

---

Stewart L. 2005. ["A neurocognitive approach to music reading."](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16597789/)
Ann N Y Acad Sci 1060:377-86.